# Hybrid app crashes on Amazon Web Service Appium test

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, appium, appium-android

I am trying to test an hybrid app on Amazon Web Services Device Farm. It crashes. Do Appium tests on hybrid apps work on AWS Device Farm?
They say they work... but do they allways work?

My guess is that the crash has to do with inconsistencies between AWS chromedriver and device chrome version, but I don't have a clue if that's correct.

I would like to know if is there any Appium Capability or something to fix webview errors on hybrid apps. I can't find any similar example.

The test crashes with this error:

```
test failed: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Error executing adbExec. 
Original error: 'Command '/opt/dev/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s FA75W0301076 shell am start -W -n com.hola.mundo/.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' timed out after 20000ms'; Stderr: ''; Code: 'null' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 100.72 seconds Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: 
'61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50' System info: host: 'ip-172-31-13-65', ip: '172.31.13.65', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-53-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

In the logs I can find this message:

```
Device01:16.640  9187  Error  WebViewFactory  Chromium WebView package does not exist
```

I create a simple "hello world" apk this way:

```sh
cordova create holamundo com.hola.mundo holamundo
cd holamundo/
cordova platform add android
cordova run android
```

This is the Java Appium test. It works on my devices locally. The test just reads the default div texts from the cordova app. 
I have Appium version 1.7.1 and cordova version 7.1.0 on a MacOS High Sierra. This is the test.

```java
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    public LoginPage loginPage() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            Set<String> contextNames = webdriver.getContextHandles();
            System.out.println(contextNames);
            webdriver.context(AndroidSetup.Contexts.WEBVIEW);
            WebElement loginButton = webdriver.findElement(By.id("deviceready"));
            System.out.println("button text: " + loginButton.getText() );
            takeScreenshot("", "pantallazo.png");
            Assert.assertEquals(loginButton.getText(), "DEVICE IS READY");
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new LoginPage(driver);
    }

    public void takeScreenshot(String path_screenshot, String filename) throws IOException {
        String currentContext = webdriver.getContext();
        System.out.println("current context: " + currentContext + " switching to " + AndroidSetup.Contexts.NATIVE);
        webdriver.context(AndroidSetup.Contexts.NATIVE);
        File srcFile=webdriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File targetFile=new File(path_screenshot + filename);
        FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,targetFile);
        webdriver.context(currentContext);
        System.out.println("current context: " + webdriver.getContext());
    }
}
```

I have packaged and run this same test on Amazon Web Services Device Farm, on a Google Pixel, Samsung Galaxy S8 and an LGE LG V20. The test works on LG and crashes in Google Pixel and Samsung phones.

Edit:
Here is the menu to select Appium version on AWS Device Farm right now. The error happens on all three versions.

[image: Appium version selection]

Answer (score 0):

AWS device farm supports Appium server `1.6.3`, `1.6.5`, and `1.4.16`.

So if it works for you locally with appium server `1.7.1` (that has recent chromedriver version), there is *no guarantee* it will work on older ones in the cloud: downgrade locally to 1.6.5 and see if it still works with that older chromedriver.

AWS Device Farm ignores any capabilities set in the code, so if there is nothing on AWS UI from during run setup => then there is no way you can set capability like `chromedriverExecutable` to use your custom chromedriver binary

Comment: Hello, @dmle, when you create the test it allows you to choose between Appium Versions 1.6.3, 1.6.5 and 1.7.1. It doesn't work on any of them. It depends on the device, not the Appium version.